# javascript created control values are not posting to server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

In my Html page I create a few textboxes in a loop with javascript.

code snippet from inside loop:

```
var row = myTable.tBodies[0].insertRow(rowCount);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.style.width = '40%';
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "text";
element1.className = 'textSub';
element1.id = 'txtOndNr' + rowNr;
cell1.appendChild(element1);
```

When I press the submit button I can't seem to acces their values server side. I am aware that they are not server controls etc. But I hoped to acces them through request.form("id").
Also when I check firebug, these values are not in the post values (the controls are located inside the form tags, that's not the issue).

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Extra info: ASP.NET 1.1, script is located in ASCX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that it's not the ID that is used to send form values but the NAME. If i change `element1.id = 'txtOndNr' + rowNr;` to `element1.name = 'txtOndNr' + rowNr;` I can acces these values with Request.form("txtOndNr0").

Looks like this when checking firebug http post request

```
txtOndNr0   qsdf
txtOndNr1   
txtOndNr2   qsdf
```

To me this looks like a slightly cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4):

Asp.net **keeps the states of control in view state for only which are created by asp.net**. You need to use `hidden field to store the state of newly created controls` and later access that hidden field on server for the state/data.

**In html**

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnFornewlyCreated" />
```

**In javascript**

```
document.getElementById('<%= hdnFornewlyCreated.ClientID %>').value = "stringcontainState";
```

**In code behind**

```
string state = hdnFornewlyCreated.Value; // Use this to extract state and data
```

Comment: hmm I was hoping not having to take this route, but it looks like the only possible way. My problem is that the user can create as many textboxes as he wants on that page. So I will have to store all the txtbox values in 1 hdn before postback (since I can't predict how many txtboxes there will be I cant provide the correct amount of hdn created server side). And string manipulate the results out of that hdn on the server side.

Comment: You have to store all data for all newly textboxes created in single hidden field. All you have to do is to format your data in such a way that can be interpretted and extracted on server side for each element created on client side.